# Polymorphic nested eager loading with constraints

Tags: laravel

I have this classes:

```
students-----{id,profile_id,year}

profiles-----{id}

subjects-----{id}-is learnable

groupsSbj-----{id}-is learnable

learnables----{profile_id,learnable_id,learnable_type,year}

groupssbj_subject--{subject_id,groupsbj_id}
```

I want to load a student with id 5, and it's profile, and learnables of that profile where learnables.year=student.year
I go with lazy loading

```
$student = Student::find(5);
$student->load(['profile.subjects'=>function($query) use($student){
                            $query->wherePivot('year','=',$student->year);
                        }],['profile.groupsSbj'=>function($query) use($student){
                            $query->wherePivot('year','=',$student->year);
                        }],'profile.groupsSbj.subjects');
```

If I call *$student.profile.subjects* I get subjects with constrains, but groups *$student.profile.groupsSbj* are not constrained, and if I separate it in two loads

```
$student = Student::find(5);
$student->load(['profile.subjects'=>function($query) use($student){
                            $query->wherePivot('year','=',$student->year);
                        }]);
$student->load(['profile.groupsSbj'=>function($query) use($student){
                            $query->wherePivot('year','=',$student->year);
                        }],'profile.groupsSbj.subjects');
```

Then groups are being constrained right but subjects don't, meaning they get loaded all. I may constrain them by writing the query again but I'm just curious why does it behave like that? is there some problem with laravel relationship class or am I doing something wrong cos I never used this polymorphic classes before

Comment: Try putting all arguments in a single array within the `load([ /* everything in one */ ])`

Comment: @apokryfos Works!!!

Comment: @apokryfos I didn't realize they were separated, great, thanks!